# Skyrim doesn't adjust the dungeon difficulty based on your level

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do enemies and monsters level up?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34615/how-do-enemies-and-monsters-level-up)

I completed the main quest line from the Magic Academia and then took a couple of sub quests from the secondary characters over there.

When I went into the dungeons I was able to 1 shot all the enemies and 5 shots the bosses.
I was under the impression that in Skyrim the dungeon difficulty should depend on my level, but instead doesn't look like to be the case.

Comment: Apart from the fact that there is already another question covering the same stuff, I am missing the question mark here.

Comment: Maybe you changed the difficulty to Apprentice or Novice and forgot to change it back?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Skyrim Wikia:

"Upon entering a dungeon in Skyrim the player's level will be saved/locked into position. In other words, the enemies will be similar to the level the player is when he/she first enters the dungeon. In the event of entering the dungeon later, the player should find (assuming the player has leveled up since their last visit) that they can more efficiently rid the dungeon of foes. This is due in part to the fact that the foes retained the level that the player encountered them at when he/she first entered the dungeon."

Found [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Elder_Scrolls_V:_Skyrim#Enemy_Leveling_System)

Comment: Also, dungeons have fixed level ranges, so entering a 1-10 level dungeon at 21st level will spawn the dungeon inhabitants at most 10th level, at which point one-shotting them will be a given. (Just did one of those myself.)

Comment: I guess that's the real answer... perhaps I was after _easy_ quests...