# Are dungeons locked at the level when you first enter them?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I read that dungeons are locked at the level when you first enter them.  So let's say I enter a dungeon at level 2 and then later on in the game I do a random quest (the ones you get from the inn keepers) and it sends me back to that dungeon when I am at level 45 (because I have already been to all the dungeons at this point).  Will the dungeon level reset at this point with the automatically create quest system?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do enemies and monsters level up?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34615/how-do-enemies-and-monsters-level-up)

Answer (score 2):

A dungeon is set at the level when you first enter, some dungeons however may have a minimum level and if you enter at a level lower then that it is set at its minimum.

An example could be a level 5 character enters a dungeon and all the monsters inside are set at an equivalent level lets say 4-6. That same character could enter another dungeon still at level 5 but it has a minimum level of 10, therefore the monsters are set to what a level 10 would find in a dungeon.

Enemies are reset once a week even in dungeons you have cleared. I am not sure if that alters the dungeons that you have entered and then left.

Comment: I just went through a dungeon I had cleared previously, and allowed it to reset. The monsters were still at the original (lower) level.

Answer (score 0):

I've been told (a.k.a. no reliable sources) that dungeons reset every 7 days.  When you enter a dungeon that has been reset, it will spawn new level appropriate enemies.  I'm not sure how this is impacted by a dungeon being 'cleared' though...

Update:

So I decided not to be *completely* lazy and did a quick Google search.  This is a [second-hand quote](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615803-/60983413), referring to the game guide, which I do not own, so take it as you will.

> my guide says that most dungeons will repopulate over time. It says maybe a little over a week for a location you left midway through or perhaps a month or more for a location you've cleared.

Answer (score -1):

No, when you enter a dungeon at level 2 then every monster in there is level 2-5. when you finish the dungeon, leave, then return at say level 45, when you enter all monster's level changes to 45-50

Comment: Are you sure on that Dylan Campbell? [The UESP Wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Leveling#Effects_of_Leveling) lists locations as being level-locked at your first entry, and I tend to find it quite reliable regarding game mechanics.

Comment: Incorrect, you ever went back to one of the first dungeons you have been in later in the game? You can easily notice the difference.

Answer (score -1):

Dungeons repopulate 10th days if not cleared. 30 if cleared. No source info confirms that the level is reset.

Comment: Hi Lee, do you have a source you can site for this answer?