# How am I supposed to kill the frost troll?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I've run into two frost trolls so far.

The first one I took advantage of bad pathing which I feel bad about because it ruined the game immersion.

The second one I used a full unrelenting shout and got a bunch of free shots in while it was unconscious, but then had to back off since it really didn't go down more than 1/4 of its life.  I finally took advantage of bad pathing to run past it to the end of the dungeon.

This feels really odd because I have taken down a handful of dragons, including once being attacked by two at the same time.

Is there any good strategy to kill a frost troll which won't make me feel like I'm glitching the game?

Comment: My character is now at level 10, using iron heavy armour.

Comment: The regeneration is what gets you. The first Troll I encountered... I was able to engage it from max range and unload a dozen arrows into its chest before it got to me. When I died, it was at full health. The next time I got close and opened with a Fire breath, and the beasty was dead in 6-7 additional shots.

Comment: "Supposed to" isn't always a valid assumption in a sandbox game. ;)

Comment: This question currently has *over thirty* answers. Please make sure your answer is sufficiently unique from existing answers before adding any more.

Comment: How does the phrase "kill it with fire" show up nowhere on this page? There's never been a better opportunity to say it.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Your level, your equipment, and your skillset all come into play while fighting. It is good to know that Frost trolls are weak against fire and it will stop them from regenerating health for a bit.

In low levels, they can absolutely devastate you, so make sure you are at least level 10 or so before you want to take one on.

Think of it like a deathclaw in Fallout 3: you can find them at level 1, but that doesn't mean you can fight them.

Dragons scale in level relative to you - Frost Trolls do not.

Comment: ! I thought all dungeons scaled with my level!  Is there a list somewhere of what scales and what doesn't?

Comment: @tugs you can read about level scaling [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34615/how-do-enemies-and-monsters-level-up)

Comment: It doesn't scale at every level from what I`ve experienced. It's kind of like WoW in that once you reach a minimum level it will have a range of creatures, some very easy and some very hard. Of course every once in a while you'll see a skeever or a low level bandit, but in general the scaling seems to be a range. so Frost trolls are probably a very hard encounter for you now but in a few levels they will get easier.

Comment: Fire is _the_ secret weapon to use when fighting trolls. I was lucky enough to read [this](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Troll_Slaying) book in game before encountering one. I didn't stick around and try to kill it though, instead opting to sprint by and try to stay alive to fight one another day.

Comment: Scaling is implemented as harder or easier tiers of enemies. For example, at low levels, you might see a dragon, and at high levels, you might get an ancient dragon. It seems like also some enemy types are designed for higher levels than others (at low levels, wolves will randomly spawn on the road, at high levels, saber tooth cats start spawning too, for example.) Yet there are some places where these harder enemy types are a guaranteed spawn. So, it's not always the case that the enemies will be appropriate for your level. The colder areas of the map with more snow are generally harder.

Answer (score 14):

I encountered one on the way to High Hrathgar, not sure what level I was but not too much higher than 10, I don't think. The troll one-shot Lydia, but she gets back up after a little bit, so that will distract it for a while. You can run faster than the troll, so I got a shot or two off as it was approaching, then ran past it as it started to attack. This is somewhat difficult to time right, especially in enclosed spaces, and it takes a long time, but it can be done, but only if you do more damage over time than its health regenerates, obviously. (Poisons help for that.) Fortunately for me I accidentally led the troll into one of the pilgrims at a shrine, who started attacking it. The troll focused on her for a few seconds and our combined damage was enough to kill it.

There's actually an [in-game book](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Troll_Slaying) on this topic. As it says trolls have a weakness to fire, but that's not too helpful if you're not a destruction magic user. As far as I know there are no flaming arrows, but you can enchant your bow or other weapon to deal extra fire damage.

For those who wield 1handers with shields, equip a torch, then "shield bash" the troll with the flaming torch. You will roast him a bit and have an easier time chopping him up with your 1hander. Milkdrinkers can re-equip their shields for better blocking, and true sons of Skyrim can just use their torch for the whole fight.

Comment: I found the same in-game book and just used the fire spell I started with and killed it so fast I thought it was a bug. Two hands of fire works for me fine.

Answer (score 10):

As a mage here is my advice:

Invest in "**Destruction Dual Casting**" - a level 20 destruction perk.

Dual cast Firebolt - it doesn't use very much magika and your magika recharge should be fairly close to magika use. Each shot will stagger the troll buying you precious seconds and preventing healing. It will take a minute but you can effectively kill a disabled troll - easy!

With high magika and magika regen you shouldn't even need to use any potions. And if you've got a companion they can help you out without taking any damage.

Answer (score 7):

I was level 5 when I lead the troll all the way down the stairs to the village below and let the town's people destroy it.

Comment: You realise its easier (and funnier) to let the gray beards kill it as they only use shouts at a range once then beat it unarmed?

Answer (score 7):

Alternate answer: **you don't have to kill them**

There is a frost troll that appears on the route to High Hrothgar early on in the game. You don't have to kill it. Put away your weapons (for increased running speed) and just dash around it and continue on your way.

Early on in the game, trying to kill everything you see is a recipe for death.

Answer (score 5):

At level 10, you should be wearing steel armor, not iron.

You should also upgrade the armor (whether taking blacksmith perks or not).

Don't skimp on armor perks.  Raising your armor skill from 0 to 100 gives you a x1.4 multiplier to armor.  Buying armor perks gives you a `2 * 1.5 =` x3 multiplier.

---

If you're getting one-shotted by a troll, you must be getting hit by a power attack.  To deal with power attacks, there's a few options.  best to worst:

- Get out of the way.  Just move.
- Interrupt (shield bash, bow punch, dual casted spell, land your own power attack, use a calm spell).
- Block, even if you're wielding a two hander it's good to block that.

There, now that you aren't getting one-shotted... you're in the world where armor matters.

Comment: When the difference armour makes in troll-fighting is that you get two-shotted instead of one-shotted, there is very little gain in focusing only on a measly 40% increase, or even a 3x increase.

Answer (score 5):

In terms of the High Hrothgar troll, if you check all the stones on the way up, a.k.a making the pilgramage, you get a buff that stops wild monsters from attacking you, if you don't attack them. This made the Frost Troll peaceful for me when I tried it, and I ended up just walking casually past.

Answer (score 4):

Frost = cold => doesn't like hot.

Fire Breath, Flames, incendiary swords and spells, Fire Atronach ... hammer it with any or all of those.

Answer (score 4):

For early levels I suggest you complete the companions line and get beast mode,  its got fast power attacks and if the fight gets hard its easier to run away

Answer (score 3):

I find that with all the trolls I have encountered so far, there is a place to stand where they can't attack you.  Takes some patience, because when they know that they can't hit you, they run off (and obviously regenerate).  So you tend to have to run at them, then go back to the 'special' place.  I like taking them on because you can seriously level up something whilst fighting them.  I'm a fighter, but I have conjure Frost Atronach and Fire Atronach, so last time I levelled up Archery, Conjuration and Sneak all in one battle.

But I do have problems with them, since I've been levelling up loads of different things, so I'm level 33 but still get my head handed to me when I fight them directly.  I didn't level up my armour perk, so they just hit me lots, and I die very quickly, even whilst healing as well as using my Exquisite Glass Axe.

Comment: See taking advantage of bad pathing is one of the things that makes me feel like I'm glitching the game.  My characters wouldn't be proud of their victory if they simply jumped on the magical stone every time the troll got close.  It just kind of ruins the immersion for me.

Answer (score 3):

Hide in a vantage point on a snow ledge and keep firing arrows until it dies. It may take some time but it is effective. I am also level 10, and I would recommend using the Ancient Nord Bow.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you have Unrelenting Force (must have all the three words; Fus Ro Dah!), just let it chase you and make it stand right next to the edge of a montain or a cliff and Fus Ro Dah it off the monutain or cliff and it will die.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a level 8 Nord Warrior with full steel armor and a one-handed Elven Sword that deals 16 damage. All I did to kill the first Frost Troll you encounter (the one on the steps leading to Higher Hrothgar, the monks) was have Flames in the left hand and my Elven Sword in the right. Now keep in mind, my steel armor made it so that I can be hit with **three** regular hits from him, or **two** powerful hits. My armor rating is 138, and my health is at 130.

What I did was just quickly burn the Frost troll and swing my sword once -- only once because a second swing could take enough time for him to hit you. Flames does damage-over-time which means he will burn for about a second. Make sure you see him burning, this is after you use the spell on him for about half of a second. While he's burning, what you do is move close enough for him to swing at you, jump back, and swing **once** at him after he is done swinging. Be careful as he may swing twice in a row. This makes it so that you can safely hit him after he tries to hit you; this guy does a crapload of damage.

You don't necessarily have to be wearing steel armor; I dodged most of his attacks easily. You also do **not** need any training in Destruction. I did this with level 15 Destruction, which is what your Destruction starts at.

Answer (score 2):

I was level 11 when I met my first Frost Troll, and used a paralysis potion and lots of power attacks to stagger the troll and hammer him down quickly with the aid of Lydia.

Answer (score 2):

I am a level 7 player and have already killed 3 frost trolls. I use frostbite spider's poison on my orcish handhammer and beat the crap out of them. Use relenting force, then couple of hits with orcish handhammer, then paralysis poison, couple more two handed shots using stamina and again unrelenting force to put it out of balance. If you have a helper, it is even easier.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you use all three words of unrelenting force?  45 seconds seems like a long time to stay alive before getting a second shout in.  And how many poisons have you gone through per fight?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this has already been mentioned, but there's a path to the left when you start, near the frost troll, and you can safely go around it. You and Lydia will survive.

Answer (score 2):

Go to farengar secret fire in dragons reach. Buy the fire bolt spell. Level up in destruction and you'll find killing trolls as easy as mud crabs. To add effect just use the fire shout. At level-50 destruction buy the flame cloak spell. After that you're primed for a troll. I have all this, and can take down 4–8 trolls with ease.

Answer (score 2):

Ravage health poisons (giant lichen found near Morthal + jazbay grapes found between Riften and Windhelm, easily farmable with Hearthfire), reduces the target's max health and cannot be cured without using a shrine or a potion, neither of which is an option for Frost Trolls. Add fire enchanted weapon or fire spell for extra lols.

Answer (score 1):

**SHORT ANSWER-** Brute force, good armor, and fire.

**LONG ANSWER-**
I have read a book "How To Kill a Forst Troll" it says its weakness is weapons enchanted with fire enchantments. Use any weapon (preferably a Two-Handed if they do more then 2/5 of your health in one hit) with a fire enchantment or use powerful magic, wear heavy armor, if you aren't already, improve it as much as possible, enchant them (for at least one armor peice, add a Fortify Health enchantment) or you could use a bow and the Throw Voice shout if you have it to distract it. And hit them as much as possible until you see them going to hit you, then back away hit it more, back away if its going to hit you, and if your health gets low, use Fast Healing or health restoration potions (or eat food) and repeat that until its dead. I recomend using shouts too (Fire Breath, maybe Frost Breath, Marked For Death, NOT UNRELENTING FORCE it does not work, even fully charged, trust me i haved tried before, and I believe Clear Skies staggers enemies a little bit and it recharges really fast so if it does stagger him, you can use it so you can hit him more then he can hit you).

Answer (score -1):

Freeze them near a steep slope and then cast force shout. Absolutely [hilarious](http://www.firstpost.com/topic/organization/7-studios-skyrim-frozen-fun-frost-troll-glitch-video-jLuhKSUHymM-51291-1.html)!

Answer (score -1):

I killed one at level 5 in light armour. How you ask? I simply unrelenting forced him off the cliff. However, if there's not a giant drop nearby? Equip your most balanced fast & powerful one-handed weapon, (skyforge sword if you have one), a shield and a follower. You should follow a simple patern of block, attack, block, attack in your heaviest armour whilst allowing your follower to take free shots.

Use a paralysis poison if you have it, whilst using any potions of healing you own to stay on top. Remember to possibly stop its attacks by bashing it with your shield and if all else fails run!

Perhaps let it follow you up to High Hrothgar and let it get UTTERLY DESTROYED by Graybeards if you want a good laugh, I did that, first they shouted YOL (fire) at it then hilariously beat it to death while it was unconscious with there bare hands.

Answer (score -1):

I killed the frost troll. Here's how I did it:

I went to the College of Winterhold. There is a lady standing outside the college who asks you to prove your magic ability; she asked me to cast "Conjure Flame Atronach." I told her that I didn't know the spell, so she taught it to me. I went along the path until I saw the troll; it hadn't seen me yet. I saved here because I assumed that me or one of my comrades would die.

I then summoned a Flame Atronach near it and they fought. Lydia, my housecarl, and Vigilance, my dog, joined the fight. I fought it with my claws, since I am a Khajiit, but a one-handed ax would work if you don't have claws. In my other hand I had the Healing spell. The troll almost killed me, but I ran away, healing myself until I was near full health. Then I summoned another Flame Atronach that dealt the killing blow to it. It didn't even have good stuff — it only gave me troll fat!

Keep in mind that the lady outside the College doesn't ask you to cast the same spell every time, so take your chances or save right before talking to her and try until you get the spell that you want.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using scroll of mass paralysis and then killing it with my scorching steel sword (or whatever it's called)...not an easy strategy to repeat because you need those items, but worth doing if you can because I made it out without a scratch

Answer (score -1):

I dual cast fire and hit and run. When I run out of mana I shoot arrows and run when it gets close. By doing this I was able to kill a troll I encountered at lvl 5.

Answer (score -1):

I've just defeated frost troll at level 5.
I only used fire since trolls are vulnerable to it.

When he stands close to reach you with his arms, do an immediately backstep, then launch fire on him again. You must be careful to avoid stepping back into a wall, as to avoid the troll's attacks.

During the battle I consumed ca. 7 potions of health and 2 potions of magicka.

Answer (score -1):

So I am still a level one... But if you are a true COMPANION you can use your special little transformation and you can quite literally knock them on their butts!! Easy kill.

Answer (score -1):

Enchant a bow with fire and snipe it.

Answer (score -1):

At Level 4, I dual-casted that Fire Destruction magic on it with a few perks, including the one that makes dual-casting do extra damage. Went backwards while doing it so that it could not hit me. The Troll can catch up to me, but always stops to swing its arm while I continue backwards, so it misses.

Took close to (but not quite) half its health when I ran out of magika. I avoided the Troll but stayed close. Soon enough it focused on Lydia, my housecarl. She falls quickly but buys me a few seconds. I equipped the Axe of Whiterun and some vanilla poison, then went melee on the creature's exposed back. A couple solid hits paired with Lydia's blows took it down.

At Level 5 I just killed a second one with the same strategy, minus the poison, plus a Shout.

Took a handful of failed tries on each one, though.

Answer (score -1):

Here are some good ways to kill frost trolls:

### Combat

Use a shield to block the frost troll's attacks. You can also stagger them by pressing attack while holding block.

### Weakness

Since frost trolls rely to the cold, use flames on the frost trolls. You could use a flame sword, a flame spell, the fire breath shout, or summon a flame atronatch to kill it. It's that simple.

### Extra Help

If you still can't fight, get some followers! Use some of the tools above to help kill the frost troll. Make sure your follower has a weapon with the flame affect or if he or she's a mage cast flame spells, or even a flame staff!

### Extra Feature

There is a book that tells you how to kill frost trolls and how to protect yourself against them. It's called **How to Kill a Frost Troll**. It'll give you more information on how to defend yourself and fight frost trolls.