# What is the difference between "Damage Health" and "Ravage Health"?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've been experimenting with Alchemy in Skyrim, and I've noticed that I've acquired two distinct alchemical effects: "Damage Health" and "Ravage Health". They both cause instant poison damage, so what's the difference? Why do some ingredients give "Damage Health" while others give "Ravage Health instead?"

Comment: I always thought ravage was just a stronger damage health?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ravage Health reduces your maximum HP. Damage Health deals damage.

You can test the effects on yourself with the following potions:

- Red Mountain Flower + Void Salts (Fortify Stamina + Damage Health)
- Eye of Saber Cat + Silverside Perch (Restore Stamina + Ravage Health)

Comment: So Ravage Health has a duration, I assume?

Comment: Correct, it's temporary, at least for the player. I'll have to test it on an enemy. The main advantage is that you can make a poison that deals both Damage and Ravage, for double effect.

Comment: Ravage is also good for foiling regenerating enemies, [such as trolls](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39011/how-am-i-supposed-to-kill-the-frost-troll).

Answer (score 2):

I just tested it myself by combining a harmful effect with a good effect, allowing me to drink the poison. Ravage does not decrease maximum, but rather is a very, very strong DoT effect that lasts 10 seconds. I took something that ravaged magicka by 12 points, and I soon lost half my total mana as the timer counted down - I had 194 total mana. This effect wore off after 10 seconds and the good effects of the potion continued working. My maximum did not seem affected.

Comment: are you sure that wasn't "lingering damage magicka" because that is exactly what it would do