# How do I defeat a Frost Troll?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How am I supposed to kill the frost troll?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39011/how-am-i-supposed-to-kill-the-frost-troll)

Whenever I go up the path to High Hrothgar to complete the quest "The Way Of The Voice" I keep running into this Frost Troll and since I am quite new to the game he keeps killing me with one hit. The weapons that I have in my equipment are Ancient Nord Greatsword of Cold, Axe of Whiterun, Iron Warhammer, Steel Greatsword, Ancient Nord Greatsword, Iron Battleaxe, Iron Greatsword, Steel Mace and Steel Sword. What is the best weapon to use against him? ... or is it best to just use magic ? If not any of these, is there some way to get past him unnoticed ?

Answer (score 4):

"fly you fools!" - Gandalf

You don't *have* to kill everything that stands in your way. You can run past the Frost Troll. They don't chase you that far. I ran into the the troll at about level 6 and it kept creaming me. Then I realized I could

1. Avoid the troll by running past it or going around the mountain (warning - I heard you might run into an ice/frost wolf on the other side of the mountain)
2. Go do some side quests to level up more.

The Skyrim main mission can be delayed so that you have a good XP level to meet its challenges. Also, remember that in Skyrim, there are many ways to complete your objectives. It's very open ended.

Comment: It just keeps running after me ! I ran and ran and ran but it keeps following

Comment: Did you sprint? Crouch and approach the ledge that it's on. Once it sees you, don't attack, just use sprint (ALT) to bound past. It helps if you get off the path and take the immediate shortcut through some rocks. Or you can quest around a bit more and then come back to the main story. They become pretty easy to kill later on (lvl 11 or so).

Comment: @Shadezguy how about using a fire spell on it?

Answer (score 1):

Frost Trolls are vulnerable against fire. I play a mage, so fire spells are my usual way to attack and proved very good against frost trolls. So if you're not good at fire spells try to get a weapon that also inflicts fire damage. Ideally a bow to do some hart hitting ranged attacks before going into melee range.

Comment: So is the "Flames" Magic Spell good ?

Comment: Should work ok... otherwise try getting him with arrows as much as you can first, then flames and finish him off with some melee.

Comment: I prefer Firebolt or Fireball, but Flames is okay too.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't fight it yet, but here is my strategy for strong boss fights:

1. First of all, bring companion with you, Lydia is good choice as she's very strong and last long.
2. Equip your most powerful weapon (i.e. weapon doing most damage), let your companion attack and do power attacks then back off and don't let the troll hit you, eventually Lydia will catch his attention again.
3. You can also buy Healing Hands spell and heal your companion while she fights the troll so she won't die.

As that specific monster is vulnerable to fire, you can shoot fireball from a distance and be careful not to hit the companion.