# Do low level items start to become incredibly rare at high levels in The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm collecting items in Skyrim, and I need to know if low level items, such as minorly enchanted weapons/armor (Blessed Iron Dagger, Steel Battleaxe of Dismay) or base unenchanted items (Iron Sword, Leather Armor), will start to become very rare if not dissapear at higher levels.

Comment: [Related?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34615/how-do-enemies-and-monsters-level-up)

Comment: I think I’ve seen low-level items lying around, and I’m level 106 or something ridiculous like that. Not sure though.

Comment: Just a note.  Those randomly generated enchanted weapons can all be replicated by yourself with the Enchantment skill, so there's really no point of collecting them.  You take the enchanted item to an enchantment table, disenchant it to learn the enchantment, and then you can just make your own.  Any gear you cannot disenchant are unique, so keep those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## **No.**

Shop keepers do not end up with an entire inventory of Daedric/Glass equipment when you reach high levels.

The list simply expands, with bias towards low/mid range, with the rarer items still actually being rare.

Before a certain level, they simply will not exist.  The Paralysis enchantment for example.  It is level locked.  However, after you reach a certain level, it is simply available, but is still rare.  Shop hunting for that Water Breathing enchantment is something you do have to do if you want it bad enough.

Even at late game, enemies are not loaded to the brim with top tier gear (unlike Oblivion... where random Bandits will have couple pieces of Glass gear).

Also, not all areas scale fully to your level.  The starting area's bandit cave will not, for example, contain Daedric stuff just because you reached the appropriate level.  It has a maximum level that it can scale to, so it limits the quality of items it can contain.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Several enchants to become unobtainable at higher levels. See the other answers. Since it is the accepted answer it would be good if you edited it

Comment: Then post a correct answer and let people vote. Comments are for clarification of answers, not to refute them and get the author to change it.

Comment: Comments are for clarifying answers. I have done so with my comment. The edit button is also available to make the best answer possible and I encourage you to do so. Or else I would ask autumnstorm451 to unaccept your answer and instead accept a correct answer

Comment: To say that my answer is "wrong" and then I need to change it, is not clarifying anything. It is outright asking me to change my answer. I stand behind my answer until I see information where enchantments are actually impossible to get (not nearly, ACTUALLY). I have no information that says enchantments cease to exist, but that it becomes rarer and rarer due to the expanding list of available enchantments, with higher and higher preference for higher level enchantments.

Comment: UESP: "After level 20 it is no longer possible to find the Necklace of Poison Immunity and the Necklace of Poison Resistance as random loot, in NPCs' pockets, or at normal merchants." You could also just play through the game, get yourself to a mid-game or end-game level, and then try to obtain every enchantment. One might even assume that anyone who bothered to answer this question would've done so. If you had, you would discover that some are unobtainable. That exactly what happened to me which led me to this thread, a top google result, with its wrong answer. Let's correct the record.

Comment: There are details that are specific to the vanilla, and the Unofficial Patch apparently fixes it. However, even in base vanilla, your spouse can still sell it, so strictly speaking, it still is available even with vanilla, but it is getting more obscure. In addition to all that, Poison Resist just doesn't work for most poison effect to begin with, so the vanilla version doesn't help with most poisons. There's just a lot of useless detail with this that I don't want to bother getting all the details and changing my answer. You're free to post your own.

Comment: Read up on all the details at the [UESP discussion page.](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Resist_Poison). Honestly I can't be bothered to make an update to a 5 year old answer on something I don't care about...

Comment: You already posted a comment disagreeing with the more correct answer 5 years ago, so it's no surprise.

Answer (score 2):

### Mostly no, but watch for two specific enchants

According to UESP, the [muffle](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Muffle_(effect)) and [waterbreathing](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Waterbreathing_(effect)) enchantments are difficult to find at low levels and nearly impossible to find at higher levels.  This is especially annoying because these enchantments happen to share an unusual property: enchanting them always produces an item of the same potency regardless of the soul gem size.  This makes them useful for enchanting junk that you plan on selling (because you can do it with petty souls instead of having to burn grand souls for maximum profit).

Comment: Anecdotally I find this to be incorrect, simply because both of these enchants are such a PITA to find, and they actually don't give me significant amount of cash improvement.  I just use whatever most expensive enchant I have on a weapon and go my merry way.  It's usually Damage Stamina.  If I find Banish or Paralyze at later levels, the item becomes 1k+ off a petty soul already.  If I want to max out cash on a piece of jewelry, it is double enchant with Carry Weight and Fortify Sneak using a Grand Soul.

Comment: There's also another reason for their rarity.  Muffle will *only* appear on shoes, and Waterbreathing will *only* appear for an amulet.  This naturally reduce their appearance rate.

Comment: Three specific enchants, cause resist poison should also be on the list. That is, necklace of poison resistance (50%) only appears from vendors at levels 5-9, necklace of disease resistance (50%) only appears at levels 10-14, necklace of disease immunity (100%) at levels 15-19, and necklace of disease immunity (100%) at levels 20 and up. And since those necklaces are the only sources of poison/disease resist, the poison resist enchantment becomes unobtainable once you're above level 20.

Comment: @ziggurism nevermind that I never even though about bothering with any of those enchants, but where are your numbers coming from? AFAIK, enchants don't "stop" appearing like that for any of the low level enchantments, even Muffle or Waterbreathing, so it is very strange for this specific enchantment to "disappear".

Comment: @Nelson according to UESP, Muffle and Waterbreathing stop appearing at lvl 70. It's not clear to me whether that means zero chance, or just practically zero chance. But resist poison literally cannot occur above lvl 20, this steam discussion goes into more detail why not. https://steamcommunity.com/app/72850/discussions/0/357286033299801400/

Comment: here is another discussion about it https://en.uesp.net/forums/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=35646

Answer (score 0):

### Kind of...

Skyrim uses [levelled list](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Leveled_Lists) to match the loot to your level, so citizens upgrade content of their pockets from garnets to diamonds, but not every list of loot is levelled one - I still remember finding iron daggers and leather armour in chests at higher levels, but indeed it was little bit more rare - if chest had a chance to contain a weapon, at lower levels it would be anything "iron", at higher one it would be selected from much bigger list containing anything from "iron" to "deadric".