# Does the level up occur before or after clicking the level up button?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Do we level up in Skyrim **only after clicking** the level up button?

Say for example, I don't level at all at say level 15 and the skills just stack, will the **enemies stay at the same level** (lv 15 or so) until I click *level up* or is it calculated based on my skill value and level accumulation...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Do we level up in Skyrim only after clicking the level up button?

As Ben said, you can still gain experience and level up individual skills. However, yes, **your level only goes up after you have selected to level up**. The [wiki](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Leveling#Leveling_Decisions) offers much more information.

To answer your other question:

> Will the enemies stay at the same level?

For all intents and purposes, **yes**. There is a really good answer already for this [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34615/how-do-enemies-and-monsters-level-up), so I will not rehash.

Answer (score 8):

Yes and no.

You still do gain experience, even if it doesn't change the XP bar. However, until you choose your stat to improve, you still are effectively the same "level".

Your skills however, do still level up, allowing you to apply skill points to other level skills. Again, however, this is only accessible after you "*level up*".

So, if you choose not to level up, but run around and kill enough people to gain an additional level, you will level up twice.

Comment: What about the enemies? They won't scale if I stop levelling? (sand-bagging)

Comment: No, I don't believe so, but I can't prove that at this point in time

Comment: Iv had fun with that one. Use the console to set my level on character up with a level 100 skill with advskill, then level up to somewhere between 8 and 15 in one go. I sometimes even reset their level back to one and do it again (usually by making the skill legendary) and get tons of skillpoints. Sometimes you just want to mess around and have all the perks. since there is no command to give you perk points.